# Custom, Dynamic Pricing Magento

Tags: php, magento, e-commerce

I'm about to embark on extending Magento to allow for products price to be calculated by a series of configurable options in a more robust way that is currently implemented e.g. based on width x height + optionalfeature x area etc.

I'm thinking of using `Event/Observer` to accomplish this, but I'm just wondering a) are there any security implications of this and b) is it considered best practice? I'm sure this functionality is fairly well-trodden ground so if anyone has a recommended way to implement this I would be very grateful as I'm not massively familiar with Magento.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that easily by binding to checkout_cart_product_add... and checkout_cart_product_update... events, just keep in mind that if you use multiple currencies, a custom price won't be recalculated after the user switches currency. You'll have to handle currency conversion by yourself in your observer.